# How to convert List<Tuple<string, int>> to string[]?

Tags: c#, .net, arrays

The method

```
static List<Tuple<string, int>> F(string root, int rootLevel)
{
    List<Tuple<string, int>> result = new List<Tuple<string, int>>();

    foreach (var item in Directory.EnumerateDirectories(root))
    {
        try
        {
            result.Add(new Tuple<string, int>(item, rootLevel + 1));

            result.AddRange(F(item, rootLevel + 1));
        }
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException ex)
        {
            string tried = "";
        }

    }

    return result;

}
```

Then in the constructor i'm using it

```
var dirs = F(textBox3.Text, 0);
var deep = (from d in dirs
            orderby d.Item2 descending
            select d).FirstOrDefault().Item2;

Search_Engine se = new Search_Engine();
se.Run();
```

The problem in this case is that `se.Run();` should return `string[]` .
And `dirs` is `List<Tuple<string, int>>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this:

```
var dirs = F(textBox3.Text, 0);

Search_Engine se = new Search_Engine();
se.Run(dirs.Select(item => item.Item1).ToArray());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easily on your own, like this:

```
var length = dirs.Count();
string[] array = new string[length];
for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
  array[i] = dirs[i].Item1;
}
//array is now what you want
```